# Symfony2 use a single class out of the box - MessageDigestPasswordEncoder

Tags: class

Hi everyone here is my question:

I have an external project that has to use the MessageDigestPasswordEncoder from Symfony2, here is my code. I dont get it included correctly:

```
require_once "../htdocs/vendor/autoload.php";
$loader->registerNamespace('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder', '../htdocs/vendor/symfony/security/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php');

$encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder();
$password = $encoder -> encodePassword($password, '');
```

Here is my error message:

```
Warning: require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\workspace_aps\gitlist\htdocs\vendor\autoload.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.') in C:\workspace_aps\gitlist\htdocs\vendor\autoload.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means vendor libraries are yet to install, or if already installed then you can try to update vendor libraries.

If you need to install all vendor libraries then install curl, composer.

**Install curl**

sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install php5-curl (this i executed after getting following exceptions)

**Install Composer**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Run Composer**

```
sudo php composer.phar
```

This command will show all available options

**Install vendor libraries**

```
sudo php composer.phar install
```

(meaning of this :  Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json)

If you already have every thing installed, try to **update existing vendor libraries**..

```
sudo php composer.phar update
```